# Chaging the output directory of CMake generated files

Tags: cmake

My project has this structure :

```
root
|- src/
|- bin/
|- include/
|- CMakeFiles/
|- CMakeLists.txt
```

When i run the `cmake` command it generates some files : `CMakeCache.txt` and `cmake_install.cmake` there is a way to send it automatically in the CMakeFiles or just to delete it afterwards ?

I want to use the cmake only (not a command line combo like `cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" && rm -f CMakeCache.txt cmake_install.cmake`)

Comment: Why do you want to delete them? Maby you can use add_custom_command or add_custom_target.

Comment: i'm using CLion and if i use both command line and CLion to compile. CLion just don't like it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is better to use out-of-source build tree.

Create new directory `build`:

```
root
|- src/
|- bin/
|- include/
|- CMakeFiles/
|- CMakeLists.txt
build
```

and run `cmake` in the `build` directory:

```
cd build
cmake ../root
```

All CMake generated files and build artifacts will be located in the build tree and will not pollute source directory.

It is a recommended way to work with CMake : http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Out-of-source_build_trees

Answer (score 3):

I've found a way to do it not buy CMake but using the makefile

```
if(UNIX)
    add_custom_target (distclean @echo cleaning for source distribution)

    add_custom_command(
        COMMENT "distribution clean"
        COMMAND make
        ARGS -C ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} clean
        COMMAND find
        ARGS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} -name "CMakeCache.txt" | xargs rm -rf
        COMMAND find
        ARGS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} -name "CMakeFiles" | xargs rm -rf
        COMMAND find
        ARGS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} -name "Makefile" | xargs rm -rf
        COMMAND find
        ARGS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} -name "*.cmake" | xargs rm -rf
        COMMAND find
        ARGS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} -name "*.qm" | xargs rm -rf
        COMMAND rm
        ARGS -rf ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/install_manifest.txt
        TARGET  distclean
    )
endif(UNIX)
```

and then  I just have to do `make distclean`

Comment: Great, it works for you. But it is not advised by the guys how provide CMake.

Comment: Yes, CMake advises to make out of sources builds (like in a `build` or `tmp`repository). But if you mess up or someone mess up this can be useful. And that's also why i've accepted the other answer not this one.