# CMake cannot generate protocolbuf headers and source files on Windows

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am trying to compile a .proto file on Windows using CMake (version 3.23.1). To this aim, I am using documentations that can be found [here](https://medium.com/3yourmind/generate-grpc-source-files-using-cmake-ec3acd246b45) and [here](https://www.f-ax.de/dev/2020/11/08/grpc-plugin-cmake-support.html). But at the end, the `.cc` and `.h` files are not generated. Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
project(test_proto)    
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)

set(Protobuf_DIR "C:/grpc/debug/cmake")
set(gRPC_DIR "C:/grpc/debug/lib/cmake/grpc")
set(ZLIB_ROOT "C:/zlib/debug")
set(c-ares_DIR "C:/grpc/debug/lib/cmake/c-ares")

find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)

set(PROTO_FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/proto/server.proto)
add_library(test_proto ${PROTO_FILES})

target_link_libraries(test_proto
   PUBLIC protobuf::libprotobuf
   PUBLIC gRPC::grpc
   PUBLIC gRPC::grpc++
)

set(PROTO_BINARY_DIR  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tmp")
set(PROTO_IMPORT_DIRS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/proto")

get_target_property(grpc_cpp_plugin_location gRPC::grpc_cpp_plugin LOCATION)
message(STATUS  " The value of grpc cpp location is: ${grpc_cpp_plugin_location}")

protobuf_generate(
    TARGET test_proto
    LANGUAGE cpp
    OUT_VAR PROTO_GENERATED_FILES
    IMPORT_DIRS ${PROTO_IMPORT_DIRS}
    PROTOC_OUT_DIR "${PROTO_BINARY_DIR}")

protobuf_generate(
    TARGET test_proto
    OUT_VAR PROTO_GENERATED_FILES
    LANGUAGE grpc
    GENERATE_EXTENSIONS .grpc.pb.h .grpc.pb.cc
    PLUGIN "protoc-gen-grpc=${grpc_cpp_plugin_location}"
    IMPORT_DIRS ${PROTO_IMPORT_DIRS}
    PROTOC_OUT_DIR "${PROTO_BINARY_DIR}")

message(STATUS " The generated files are located in: ${PROTO_GENERATED_FILES}")
```

After running the above CMake file using this command:

```
cmake.exe -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -S D:\cmake-test -B D:\cmake-test
```

I am getting this output:

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30137.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30137.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: c:/VS/MVS16117/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: c:/VS/MVS16117/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found ZLIB: C:/zlib/debug/lib/zlibd.lib (found version "1.2.11")
-- Found OpenSSL: optimized;C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/lib/VC/libcrypto64MD.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/lib/VC/libcrypto64MDd.lib (found version "3.0.3")
--  The value of grpc cpp location is: C:/grpc/debug/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin.exe
--  The generated files are located in: D:/cmake-test/tmp/proto/server.grpc.pb.h;D:/cmake-test/tmp/proto/server.grpc.pb.cc;D:/cmake-test/tmp/proto/serverPLUGIN;D:/cmake-test/tmp/proto/serverprotoc-gen-grpc=C:/data/tools/grpc/v1.15.1-2/win64/release/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin.exe
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/cmake-test
```

without any errors. But the .h and .cc files are not generated. Any ideas?

Comment: My understanding is that cmake won't generate the protobuf, but will create a rule in a make file to generate them. You need to call `make` to generate the protobuf h/cpp files.

Comment: Offtopic: it is very bad practice to have absolute paths in `CMakeLists.txt` especially when they are so user specific.

Comment: @MarekR You are right. But it is only a very simple minimal reproducible example extracted from a huge code base.

Comment: CMake advises to make out of sources builds (like in a build or tmp repository). This might be the answer you are looking [for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27176692/8458465). It is a direct quote from the comment of the other answer from the link.

Comment: @0x26res I even cannot Build the project. During build, I am facing this issue: `error MSB4023: Cannot evaluate the item metadata "%(RootDir)". The item metadata "%(FullPath)" cannot be applied to the path "D:\cmake-test\tmp\proto\serverprotoc-gen-grpc=C:\grpc\debug\bin\grpc_cpp_plugin.exe". The given path's format is not supported.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue of my problem was related to having an old version of gRPC. By migrating to a new version (v1.56.0), everything is working as expected.

In addition, as mentioned in the comments, the generated files are created at build time. For more info [check here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/e1faf09604d26cc6803970815f91225b220175d4/docs/cmake_protobuf_generate.md).